# hibernate commit data before request ends

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jta

I'm using Hibernate in my web application and I need to send data instantly to database. Now I can see data on database only when request end, so I suppose that I'm using session-per-request pattern but I never set it, maybe is default behaviour.

web request can take several seconds, usually 5-6 seconds, meanwhile other process can read data from database and I can have inconsistant state.

I try everything but without success, this is my code for update data :

```
EntityManager em = EntityMan.getEMF().createEntityManager();       
try {
    em.find(Tel.class, tel.getTelId());
    em.merge(tel);
    em.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I try using session and transaction commit but doesn't work how I would like

```
EntityManager em = EntityMan.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    try {
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        em.close();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);
        session.merge(tel);            
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="MyProject_EJB" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:/ds/MyProjectDS</jta-data-source>
<class>....</class>
<class>....</class>

<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
  <!-- Caching properties -->
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>

  <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider" />-->
  <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="ehcache.xml"/>
  <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>-->
  <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />-->
  <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
  <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4"/>
  <!--
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.JndiMultiplexedJBossCacheRegionFactory"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cachefactory" value="java:CacheManager"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity" value="mvcc-entity"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.query" value="local-query"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/> -->
</properties>
```

Comment: How are transactions managed (which framework do you use) in your application?

Comment: I use struts for web application, nothing else. Application server is JBoss.
transaction-type = "JTA" in persistence.xml

Comment: Then simply start a new nested transaction somewhere in the middle of the request where it suits your requirements.

Comment: the first code is a transaction that I run in action method, after that code I have some services call and later the method end. Only when scope of request is closed I can see data changed in db. How can I run a transaction that can close itself and make data persistent instantanly before request end ?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic - That does not work.  Hibernate does not support nested transactions, you get an `IllegalStateException` thrown on the second `beginTransaction()`.

Comment: @BadZen I've successfully nested hundreds of them so far. You have to do it on a new `Session` of course (done automatically on all modern containers like Spring and JEE implementations like JBoss in this question).

Comment: If you start a parallel `Session`, that's not nesting.  That's a parallel transaction.   Nested transactions support checkpointing.  Hibernate does not support nested transactions, as per the documentation:   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html

Comment: (also, check section 8.6 specifically, it is Generally Considered Harmful to do what you are describing...)